# MS Teams + Graph API - cant get chat id between user and teamsApp

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams

I want to send a proactive messages from our CRM directly to the user in Teams.

My approach:

- created aplication (AAD), granted api permissions
- BOT is registred on https://dev.botframework.com/ and linked to Teams and installed aplication.

Now i want get chat id between user and app:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userscopeteamsappinstallation-get-chat?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

My get request endpoint:

/users/USERID/teamwork/installedApps/NjXXXXXXXXXXXXhMjA=/chat

ends with error 400: bad request - no more information provided

Im doing something wrong ? Thank you

App is visible on this endpoint - /appCatalogs/teamsApps/ (available app)
App is visible on this endpoint - /teamwork/installedApps/ (installed app in user Teams)
I can uninstall app and again install via graph